# When insertRowsAtIndexPath gets called, the cell size gets compacted

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When insertRowAtIndexPath... gets caled, the cells size changes to a very compact size. But when the cells go out of view, and come back, they are back to normal.

Here is the code:

```
- (IBAction)addRow:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger row = [self.rowArray count] - 1;
    [self.rowArray insertObject:@"cellIDRowSeven" atIndex:row];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
    [self.myTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

(When I do `[self.myTableView reoladData];`, it works fine, but I don't get the animation.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set `estimatedRowHeight` for `tableView`? And also btw it's better just do `self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` if all cells will have same height.

Comment: I can't do `estimatedRowHeight` because all cells have different heights.

Comment: I have a table view with dynamic cell height in one of my project too. As long as you set the auto layout constraints correct the estimatedRowHeight will only be a guideline for table view to render cells. It's "estimated" so you'll still have dynamic cell heights. And in a way I think it's required to set `estimatedRowHeight` if you use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. (I'm not 100% sure on that part though. I always use them together.)

Comment: Can I use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for the estimated row height?

Comment: @Mike, I think `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` is for row height only, and because it's "automatic" you have to supply an estimated row height with it... That's just my own understanding for it.